# Rails5 - ruby 2.2.3 // how ActiveSupport::TimeZone changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Asking a question yesterday ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157457/rails-query-by-timezone-during-daytime/36158119#36158119)) about time zones, the following is not working with rails 5 running on ruby 2.2.3 :

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map
```

Where can one read about the differences of use between with this new version ? What could be the way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to look into the [current source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L248) for the `TimeZone` in `ActiveSupport`: the `zones_map` method [has been made private](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/89d48fb342279767b1446c8233ab6abefca7919c), so I guess you are getting this error under Rails 5:

```
NoMethodError: private method 'zones_map' called for ActiveSupport::TimeZone:Class
```

So now you have two options: either use `send` to call the private method anyway:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.send(:zones_map)
```

Or, even better, if all you need is `values` of this map (as suggested in the [answer to your yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36158119/1544012)), then there is no need to hack around the `zones_map`. You can use the `all` method instead:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

According to the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L217), the `all` method is equivalent to `zones_map.values.sort` and it is a normal public method so there's no need to `send` anything.